# How to use axios with Tabulator-vue using pagination-remote

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, tabulator

Spoiler Alert, this is different from: [Tabulator + Nuxt.js: How to use axios in callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941201/tabulator-nuxt-js-how-to-use-axios-in-callbacks)

I am using the Tabulator component through its vue wrapper: https://github.com/angeliski/vue-tabulator mostly to display data using the remote pagination mode (that is the server-side stuff).

I looked at the documentation: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/page#remote and seems there is nothing that allows me to perform the API call (by myself).

There are some options to adjust (like the url, the header, but I don't have my hands on the actual thing calling the API) the call made by the underlying function used by Tabulator, but nothing to replace it entirely.

I would like to reuse axios which is already configured for auth + sso in my vue project for every call performed by the Tabulator component.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Tabulator allows you to override the built in ajax loader by passing a function to the ***ajaxRequestFunc*** setup option.

The function should return a promise that resolves with the table data.

More info can be found in the [Overriding the Request Promise](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/data#ajax-promise) section of the ajax documentation.

```
function queryRealm(url, config, params){
    //url - the url of the request
    //config - the ajaxConfig object
    //params - the ajaxParams object

    //return promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        //do some async data retrieval then pass the array of row data back into Tabulator
        resolve(data);

        //if there is an error call this function and pass the error message or object into it
        reject();
    });
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxRequestFunc:queryRealm,
});
```